# ViewState across servers in a SharePoint Farm

Tags: web-config, viewstate

When a new server is added to a farm will SharePoint automatically synchronise the machine key such that view state will work across the farm, or is a manual operation required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No manual operation is required as long as you are using Out of the box box Sharepoint components.

If you are using some custom code, please clarify what is it you are trying to do.